# Different number of blocks allocated using stat() and ls -s

Tags: c

I was trying to get number of blocks allocated to a file using C. I used the stat struct with its variable called st_blocks. However this is returning different number of blocks as compared to ls -s. Can anybody explain the reason for this and if there is a way to correct this?

Comment: Could you show what values you got?

Comment: According to man, stat uses 512B block size. Maybe ls uses a different one. You can sort it out using `ls -s --block-size=512` and check the output.

Comment: `man 2 stat`: st_blocks is the number of 512 bytes blocks. st_blocksize is the actual block size of the underlying filesystem.

Answer (score 6):

There is no discrepancy; just a misunderstanding. There are two separate "block sizes" here. Use `ls -s --block-size=512` to use 512 byte block size for `ls`, too.

---

The [`ls -s`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) command lists the size allocated to the file in user-specified units ("blocks"), the size of which you can specify using the `--block-size` option.

The `st_blocks` field in [`struct stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) is in units of 512 bytes.

You see a discrepancy, because the two *"block sizes"* are not the same. They just happen to be called the same name.

Here is an example that you can examine this effect. This works on all POSIXy/Unixy file systems (that support [sparse file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file)), but not on FAT/VFAT etc.

First, let's create a file that but is one megabyte long, but has a hole at the beginning (they read zeros, but are not actually stored on disk), with a single byte at end (I'll use `'X'`).

We do this by using `dd` to skip the first 1048575 bytes of the file (creating a "hole", and thus a sparse file on filesystems that support such):

```
printf 'X' | dd bs=1 seek=1048575 of=sparse-file count=1
```

We can use the [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) utility to examine the file. Format specifier `%s` provides the logical size of the file (1048576), `%b` the number of blocks (`st_blocks`):

```
stat -c 'st_size=%s st_blocks=%b' sparse-file
```

On my system, I get `st_size=1048576 st_blocks=8`, because the actual filesystem block size is 4096 bytes (= 8×512), and this sparse file needs only one filesystem block.

However, using `ls -s sparse-file` I get `4 sparse-file`, because the default ls block size is 1024 bytes. If I run

```
ls --block-size=512 -s sparse-file
```

then I see `8 sparse-file`, as I'd expect.

Answer (score 4):

"Blocks" here are not real filesystem blocks. They're convenient chunks for display.

`st_blocks` is using *probably* 512 byte blocks. See [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html).

`st_blksize` is the *preferred* block size for this file, but not necessarily the actual block size.

BSD `ls -s` always uses 512 byte "blocks".  OS X, for example, uses BSD ls by default.

```
$ /bin/ls -s index.html 
560 index.html
```

GNU ls appears to use 1K blocks unless overriden with `--block-size`.

```
$ /opt/local/bin/gls -s index.html 
280 index.html
```

`printf("%lld / %d\n", buf.st_blocks, buf.st_blksize);` produces `560 / 4096`. The 560 "blocks" are in 512 byte chunks, but the real filesystem blocks are 4k.

The file contains 284938 bytes of data...

```
$ ls -l index.html 
-rw-r--r-- 1 schwern staff 284938 Aug 11  2016 index.html
```

...but we can see it uses 280K on disk or 70 bytes.

[image]

Note that OS X further confuses the issue by using 1000 bytes for a "kilobyte" instead of the correct 1024 bytes, that's why it says 287 KB for 70 4096 KB blocks (ie. 286720 bytes) instead of 280 KB. This was done because hard drive manufacturers started using 1000 byte "kilobytes" in order to inflate their size, and Apple got tired of customers complaining about "lost" disk space.

The 4K block size can be seen by making a tiny file.

[image]

Comment: 1000 bytes in kilobyte is correct by international standards. For 1024 bytes there is kibibyte, or kiB. Please don't spread misinformation.

Comment: @IlyaPopov The great thing about standards is there's so many to choose from! You're referring to the SI and ISO/IEC standard decimal kilobyte. Decimalization of the byte is fairly recent, the last 10 or 20 years. And, unlike other decimalization attempts, creates a clash between how they're structured and used in the field (ie. binary), and how the layman understands them. It causes a lot of confusion. Anyhow, I believe the attempt to standardize on decimalization is a result of bandwidth and storage inflating their sizes, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to SI and ISO. This is very important for consistency: imagine we have a CPU that processes one byte every cycle and operates at speed 1 GHz. How many gigabytes per second is that? I find exactly 1 gigabyte/s to be the only reasonable answer, not 0.931 GB/s as by your definition. (I am a physicist, however.)

Comment: @IlyaPopov Yes, it works fine for clock speeds, those are a measure of frequency and not binary in nature, though they rarely run at exactly 1 or 2 or 3 Ghz or even a fixed frequency so the advantage is moot (mine are currently fluctuating around 3520.0 MHz). It's not so good for memory, storage, and bandwidth which are binary in nature and are built up in powers of 2. A 4096 byte block is a real thing. It's much easier to refer to a 4K block (meaning 4096 bytes) than a 4.096 K block. People rarely remember to specify KiB because nobody sensible uses decimal bytes.